# Http Client did not return any value and not moved another line of code

Tags: c#

When I call HTTP client like below this code did not return any response value and also did not move next line of code. just hanged.

How to solve this issue?

I called from another class file, here this function want return proper a integer value and also HTTP response.

```
// call api
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("System", new Systemmodel
{
    GuidID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    SystemIP = "124.0.098",
    SystemUserName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(SystemName) 
        ? System.Environment.MachineName 
        : SystemName,
    SystemOS = "Windows OS",
    CompanyGUID = Ad`enter code here`minName
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you mistake `SystemIP = "124.0.098"` this is not valid IP, I guess you need it to be like this `SystemIP = "124.0.0.98"`  , I AM not sure

Comment: I would think that after a while, the function would return a timeout. As @IbramReda said, this could be because of the incorrect ip address. If you wait for a while, does the function throw an exception?

Comment: Here no validation if sysem ip or not. just string value only send it api, there inserted record successfully in db. response only hanged

Comment: i checked there is no problem in ip related issue. its a task related timeout problem. please help me how to solve this issue @IbramReda